# How to specify icc_pre_subject and var_ratio in study_parameters function (powerlmm package)?

Tags: r, statistics, mixed-models, multilevel-analysis

I am trying to conduct a power analysis for studies where I use Linear Mixed Model for the analysis. I conducted a pilot study in order to see the effect sizes of the fixed effects and to see the results of random effects, which are required to fill in in a R function - study_parametor().

First, I build a lmer model using the data from the pilot study. In the model, the reaction time for the stimuli is set as the dependent variable, and the experimental condition (with 2levels), the number of trials (from 0 to 159, code as numeric values) as well as the interaction between the condition and the number of trials are included as fixed factors. The experimental condition is a between-subject condition, but the number of trials is within-subject factor - all participants go through the trials from 0 to 159. For random effects, I set the random intercept and slope for participants, and random intercept for beauty rating for each item (as a control factor). Together, the model looks like:

lmer(Reaction time ~ Condition*Number of trial + (1 + Number of trial|Subject) + (1|Beautyrating))

For power analysis I want to use a function study_parametor() in powerlmm package. In this function, we have to specify icc_pre_subject and var_ratio as the parametors for random effect variance information. What I want to do here is, to set the parametors based on the results of the pilot study.

From the tutorial, the two variables are defined as follows:

icc_pre_subject: the amount of the total baseline variance the is between-subjects. (there is a typo in the sentence in the tutorial). icc_pre_subject would be the 2-level ICC if there was no random slopes.

**icc_pre_subject = var(subject_intercepts)/(var(subject_intercepts) + var(within-subject_error))**

var_ratio: the ratio of total random slope variance over the level-1 residual variance.

**var_ratio = var(subject_slopes)/var(within-subject_error))**

Here, I am not sure what var(within-subject_error)) means, and how to specify it.

[This is the results of random effects in the model which used the pilot study data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jstUy.png)

**My question**

which number should I use for specify the icc_pre_subject and var_ratio in the function of study_parametor()

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.